# Automatic backup of mysql on ubuntu

Tags: backup, mysql

I have a Ubuntu server with a Mysql daatabase.
I would like to set up an automatic backup of this database during the night on another server (ovh for example).

I don't know what would be the best tool for that.
If someone has some advices...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37):

The easiest way to automate this task would be the combination of MySQL Dumps and a cronjob. You can find a lot of information on this topic on this and other internet sites, but for the sake of completion:

**Create a mysqldump.sh file**

Which will contain the mysql dump command we will schedule in a cron job (replace user, password and path to match your environment):

```
mysqldump -u root -p<mysql_root_password> --all-databases | gzip > /desired/backup/folder/mysqldb_`date +%F`.sql.gz
```

**Edit:** If you want the script to store the backup in a remote location, just mount the corresponding device or share and use the mount path in the script.

**Test the script**

Ensure that the script has execution permissions:

```
chmod +x /path/to/mysqldump.sh
```

Execute the script:

```
sh /path/to/mysqldump.sh
```

And test it is working correctly (The backup file will be created in the specified backup folder).

**Create and schedule a new cron job**

In a command prompt type

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add the following line at the bottom of the file:

```
30 23 * * * /path/to/mysqldump.sh
```

This will execute the script every day at 23:30.

**Extend this simple script**

There is literally loads of things you can do in order to improve this simple backup method:

- Backing up to another system
- Monitor disk space
- Email reporting
- ...

So do not end here and experiment! :-)

**Use backup-tools or cloud-based backup-services**

Although the above method is one of the easiest and can be extended to suit your specific needs, it is worth mentioning that there are other alternatives:

- backup-tools such as AutoMySQLBackup, an open-source application
  which might ease the process of configuring Email-notification,
  compression, encryption, rotation and type (e.g. incremental) of your
  backups. As for Mai 2018, it is available for Ubuntu Server through
  APT.
- cloud-based backup-services such as BackupBird, myRepono, Bitcan,
  etc. which might be interesting if you manage several
  database-servers and want to centrally manage all their backups.

Please bare in mind that I'm not related in any way to any of the above mentioned solutions and services and I'm listing them only for reference, so use them at you own risk.

> Useful Links / References:
>
> Cron -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron
>
> MySQL Dump -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Use `date +%F` - that will automatically pick a combination of year+month+date suited to the user's locale (for example, I'll get `YYYY-MM-DD`).

Comment: Oh yes, much better. I'll edit the answer :-)

Comment: +1 Good answer: exactly what is necessary here, no more, no less.

Comment: If you have to use sudo to do this operation (a) call `sudo crontab -e` and don't forget to make the script executable: `chmod +x /path/to/mysqldump.sh`

Comment: zinon - Thanks for the hints! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**There are few ways to automate backups of MySQL databases:**

1. Bash script
2. Using automysqlbackup
3. Third part tools

**Bash script**

```
# Backup storage directory 
backup_folder=/var/backups

# Notification email address 
recipient_email=<username@mail.com>

# MySQL user
user=<user_name>

# MySQL password
password=<password>

# Number of days to store the backup 
keep_day=30 

sqlfile=$backup_folder/all-database-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S).sql
zipfile=$backup_folder/all-database-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S).zip 

# Create a backup 
sudo mysqldump -u $user -p$password --all-databases > $sqlfile 

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  echo 'Sql dump created' 
else
  echo 'mysqldump return non-zero code' | mailx -s 'No backup was created!' $recipient_email  
  exit 
fi 

# Compress backup 
zip $zipfile $sqlfile 

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   echo 'The backup was successfully compressed' 
else
   echo 'Error compressing backup' | mailx -s 'Backup was not created!' $recipient_email 
   exit 
fi 

rm $sqlfile 

echo $zipfile | mailx -s 'Backup was successfully created' $recipient_email 

# Delete old backups 
#find $backupfolder -mtime +$keep_day -delete
find $backup_folder -mtime +$keep_day -delete
```

- Pros:

  - it's absolutely free
  - you can add all that you need to a bash script to automate a backup
- Cons:

  - there is a need to have a good knowledge of bash scripts to make an complicated backup process
  - it’s difficult to configure the sending of backups to the cloud

**[Automysqlbackup](https://github.com/sixhop/AutoMySQLBackup/blob/master/automysqlbackup.conf)**

```
sudo apt-get install automysqlbackup
wget https://github.com/sixhop/AutoMySQLBackup/archive/master.zip

mkdir /opt/automysqlbackup
mv AutoMySQLBackup-master.zip 
cd /opt/automysqlbackup
tar -zxvf AutoMySQLBackup-master.zip

./install.sh

sudo nano /etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf

CONFIG_configfile="/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf"
CONFIG_backup_dir='/var/backup/db'
CONFIG_mysql_dump_username='root'
CONFIG_mysql_dump_password='my_password'
CONFIG_mysql_dump_host='localhost'
CONFIG_db_names=('my_db')
CONFIG_db_exclude=('information_schema')
CONFIG_mail_address='mail@google.com'
CONFIG_rotation_daily=6
CONFIG_rotation_weekly=35
CONFIG_rotation_monthly=150

automysqlbackup /etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf
```

- Pros:

  - it's free
  - several parts of the backup process already added to the script
- Cons:

  - you may only specify a folder as the backup storage location (it's not safe)
  - there is no opportunity to remove old backup's files

**Third party tool**

If you need something ready-made, easy to use with many options you can use [SqlBak](https://sqlbak.com/).

- Pros:

  - it's free
  - it's easy to use
  - there are many storage clouds supported
  - there are different kinds of notifications
  - there is an auto deletion old backups from the clouds
  - one web interface for many DBMS servers
  - different kinds DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server)
- Cons:

  - there is no yet an opportunity to make an incremental backups