# Restoring a mysql backup

Tags: mysql, restore, database

Hello i am using a vps running ubuntu 1604 and i have done this 
[Automatic backup of mysql on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698845/automatic-backup-of-mysql-on-ubuntu/941602#941602)
but i want now to restore that backup
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using `phpmyadmin`console?

Comment: disabled it but i can enable.

Comment: How were you planning on restoring database from command line, I believe the console is better

Comment: http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution restore single MySQL Database from that backups.

Before you restore a database, you must create an empty database on the target machine and restore the database using msyql command. For example the following command will restore the restore_backup.sql file to the rsyslog database.

```
# mysql -h localhost -u root -pazzazy(this is pass root you setup) restore_backup < restore_backup.sql
```

If you want to restore a database that already exist on targeted machine, then you will need to use the mysqlimport command.

```
# mysqlimport -u root -pazzazy(this is pass root you setup) restore_backup < restore_backup.sql
```

In the same way you can also restore database tables, structures and data.

In Case with file sql.gz you can restore with command:

```
gunzip < test.sql.gz | mysql -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname]
```

And Please you can read [Backup and Restore Database .gz](http://How%20to%20Back%20Up%20and%20Restore%20a%20MySQL%20Database)

Comment: Unsafe. That will echo the password to the processlist.

Comment: Yes, with command maybe not show password and remove option` -pazzazy`. So when restore database you can login password when run command.

Comment: my database format is sql.gz  i dont think that this will work.

Comment: With database format is sql.gz you can use backup all database sql with command gzip. I'm update command backup and restore with sql.gz.