# Create crontab for MySQLdump

Tags: bash, scripts, mysql, cron

I am trying to create a crontab to do a backup to my database in MySQL, the `mysqldump` command works fine with no errors as a single command or running bash script, but when I added the bash script to the crontab file it did not execute, below is my code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -h xx.xx.xx.xxx -u wissam -p'xxxxxx' 
--all-databases | gzip > ~/Desktop/DBs/Backup"$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%p")file.sql.gz"
```

the crontab command:

```bsh
09 9    * * *   root    sh /home/ahmad/Desktop/DBs/mysqlcron.sh 2>&1>> /home/ahmad/Desktop/DBs/MySQLdump.log
```

which was added to `/etc/crontab`, after that I tried to restart the service but did not work for me, I also tried these solutions [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698845/automatic-backup-of-mysql-on-ubuntu), [2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-cron-jobs-in-ubuntu/) and [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067592/mysqldump-script-doesnt-work-in-cron) and still did not working.

Any help, please?

Comment: To capture stdout and stderr to the same log file, you need to reverse the order of redirections: `>> /home/ahmad/Desktop/DBs/MySQLdump.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crontab needs absolute paths, so besides the recommendations of Rinzwind, use either

```
09 9    * * *   root    /bin/bash /home/ahmad/Desktop/DBs/mysqlcron.sh 2>&1>> /home/ahmad/Desktop/DBs/MySQLdump.log
```

or

```
09 9    * * *   root    /home/ahmad/Desktop/DBs/mysqlcron.sh 2>&1>> /home/ahmad/Desktop/DBs/MySQLdump.log
```

Comment: should I add the absolute path of ```mysqldump``` ?

Comment: Not completely sure about `mysqldump`(and `gzip` by the way) but sure about `~/Desktop/DBs/Backup`.  Replace the `~` by the desired directory.

Answer (score 1):

Please use absolute paths.

```
mysqldump
```

and

```
~/
```

need a directory. "~" is NEVER going to get expanded to your user.

Besides that:

```
-h xx.xx.xx.xxx -u wissam -p'xxxxxx'
```

is very bad as it will echo host and password to the process list. Use ...

```
--defaults-extra-file=.mysql
```

and put at least the password in that file.

Comment: I changed the path here ```gzip > ~/Desktop/DBs/Backup``` to absolute path but did not work too

Comment: and why are you ignoring "mysqldump"?

Comment: I am not ignoring it, but I think I understood your answer in a wrong way besides all solutions and command on the internet did not mention the path of ```mysqldump``` , won I will change it as you saying